# What do I put in the function prototype when using that function with different parameters?

Tags: c

I want to use a function to fill different arrays with data by calling that function thrice.

```
// Function prototype

void fill_array();

int main()

{

   int bin_array[15], 

      prb_array[15],

      seq_array[15];

   fill_array(bin_array);

   fill_array(prb_array);

   fill_array(seq_array);

   return 0;

}
```

My question is, what parameters should I put up at the function prototype? All three?

```
// Function prototype
void fill_array(insert parameter here);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the prototype, you don't even have to put any name at all, just the type:

```
void fill_array(int[]);
```

When you *define* the function, however, you need a name. However, it can be whatever you want:

```
void fill_array(int joe[]) {
    //...
}
```

Edit: Although not directly related to the problem at hand, birryree makes an excellent point. You should usually pass the size of an array as well, since otherwise `fill_array` doesn't know how big the array is:

```
void fill_array(int[], int);

void do_stuff() {
    int bin_array[15], 

        prb_array[15],

        seq_array[15];

    fill_array(bin_array, sizeof(bin_array) / sizeof(int));
    fill_array(prb_array, sizeof(prb_array) / sizeof(int));
    fill_array(seq_array, sizeof(seq_array) / sizeof(int));
}

void fill_array(int bob[], int length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        bob[i] = i * 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably want to add a second argument to specify the number of elements, since you can not get an array's size after it's been passed to a function.

Comment: I think you mean `sizeof(bin_array) / sizeof(*bin_array)`.

Comment: Also, for prototypes, it's useful to include parameter names as they serve as documentation.

Comment: @strager: Whoops, my bad. I assumed sizeof returned elements, not byte. I've corrected it.

Comment: Thanks all, it's easy to forget the simple stuff.. I was like d'oh afterwards haha.

Comment: `size_t` is a better type to use for array lengths.

Comment: As @strager mentioned, it's better to include a parameter name for documentation purposes, so `void fill_array(int[], int);` would be better off as `void fill_array(int array[], int length);`. IDEs (well, the good ones) will show you the parameter names when doing auto-complete, which means you don't have to go and lookup what each argument is supposed to be.